# trying to change display=none to block in function

Tags: html, css

I cant figure out for the life of me why this is not working. If i put an alert it works but its not working when i want to change the display.

```
<script> 
function validatesForm() {
        var x=document.forms["MYPage"]["name"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") 
        {
            document.getElementById("errorname").style.display="block";
            return false;
        }

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="MYPage">
Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <p id="errorname"  style="color:red;       display:none;">Please fill out this field</p>

    <input type="submit" value="Validate!" onclick="validatesForm()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation function shouldn't be called from the onclick event of the submit button like you have it. Instead, it should be called from the onsubmit event of the form tag like `<form name="MYPage" onsubmit="return validatesForm();">`. Also notice the word `return` before the function call, which grabs the boolean result of the validation function and uses it to decide whether to submit or not.

This is a good tutorial and example: http://w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp